# python re remove text between < (exclusive) and last / (inclusive) in a line

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a python script to edit a library of .cpp and h. files. Because of the vagaries of unity3d and iOS native plugins I have to completely flatten its directory structure. So I must go through all the files and change this.. (for example)

```
   #include <Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2DistanceJoint.h>
```

to this..

```
   #include <b2DistanceJoint.h>
```

So I need a regex command that removes any text in a line in between < and the last / and also removes the last / .Also if there is no / then nothing happens (though I can just do that with an if statement if needs be)

Comment: yeah but I am flailing around. I'm quite rusty with python and never really 'got' re

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
code = '''#include <Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2DistanceJoint.h>
#include <Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/xyz.h> #include <Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/xyz.h>
#include <pqr.h>'''

code = re.sub("(?:(?<=^)|(?<=[\n\r]))#include\s+<[^>]*/", "#include <", code)
```

`(?:(?<=^)|(?<=[\n\r]))` ensures that the `#include` is only at the beginning of the line. So that it doesn't touch the other `#include`

Regex explanation:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\n\r]                   any character of: '\n' (newline), '\r'
                             (carriage return)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
```

Answer (score 3):

use this regex `<.*\/.*\/`

[REgex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eG5tA1)

Verify the output here : [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/GlYfqJ)

**CODE:**

```
import re

text = """#include <Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2DistanceJoint.h>"""
#print text
print re.sub(r'<.*\/.*\/','<',text)
```

**OUTPUT:**

`#include <b2DistanceJoint.h>`

Comment: Ok actually that `regex` is pretty simple :) I normally try to avoid them everything I can but that's cool :)

Comment: Yeah that worked. Only change I had to make was put the stuff after 'print' in parentheses. Thanks!, also thanks Paulo.

Comment: Actually this one didnt work for some cases where there was only one / for instance with #include <Box2D/b2DistanceJoint.h>

Comment: @GuyeIncognito : Thanks for pointing the mistake. I will update it soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this without regex if you want to, slice between the first `<` char and the last `/` char:

```
>>>s = "#include <Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2DistanceJoint.h>"
>>>s[:s.find('<')+1] + s[s.rfind('/')+1:]
'#include <b2DistanceJoint.h>'
```

Of course, maybe you stumble with a line that doesn't have any `/`, in that case I assume you'll want to leave it intact, so you can add an `if` to check that:

```
>>>s = "#include <Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2DistanceJoint.h>"
>>>if s.rfind('/') >= 0:
>>>    s = s[:s.find('<')+1] + s[s.rfind('/')+1:]
'#include <b2DistanceJoint.h>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex that you accepted actually doesn't work for a string like:

```
#include <Joints/b2DistanceJoint.h>
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/oY2sO5)

I propose a regex a bit more like this instead:

```
<[^>]*/
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hJ4gP4)

In code:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = """#include <Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2DistanceJoint.h>"""
>>> print re.sub(r"<[^>]*/", "<", text)
#include <b2DistanceJoint.h>
```